# How do you df.query() a column with a name that has an apostrophe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The column name is: Bob's Burgers

A workaround could be renaming the column... but I'm curious if you can actually query the above column or if this is indeed a limitation in the parser.

Edit: here's what I tried

```
df.query("`Bob's Burgers` == 'dfasdfa'")
```

I'm getting this error: **SyntaxError: Failed to parse backticks**

Comment: Use the *backtick* : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75314036/16120011

Comment: Right, I tried the backtick, but perhaps I'm doing it wrong.

df.query("`Bob's Burgers` == 'dfasdfa'")`

Comment: Are you getting an error or what ?

Comment: SyntaxError: Failed to parse backticks

Comment: see my Edit in the original post... Stackoverflow is thinkg my backticks are code blocks in the comments lol

Comment: @ejgza FYI, backticks do inline code formatting. [If you put double backticks before and after the code, the formatting works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82722/343832): ``df.query("`Bob's Burgers` == 'dfasdfa'")``

Comment: Perhaps make life easy on yourself and clean the column names.  (e.g.: Lower case, no spaces, no punctuation, underscore separated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a limitation of the parser when dealing with **an odd number of a quote character**. For comparison, I can reproduce the same issue with the column called `Bob"s` and query `` `Bob"s` == "dfasdfa" ``, but not with the column called `'Bob's` and query `` `'Bob's` == 'dfasdfa' ``. I'm using Pandas 1.4.4.

So, simply switch quote characters, for example:

- ```
  df.query('''`Bob's Burgers` == "dfasdfa"''')
  ```
- ```
  df.query("""`Bob's Burgers` == "dfasdfa" """)  # Note the trailing space
  ```

Or use a variable:

- ```
  v = 'dfasdfa'
  df.query("`Bob's Burgers` == @v")
  ```
- ```
  col = df["Bob's Burgers"]
  df.query("@col == 'dfasdfa'")
  ```

  - Note that it's not possible to use a variable for the column *name*:

    ```
    col = "Bob's Burgers"
    df.query("@col == 'dfasdfa'")
    ```

    ```
        ...
    KeyError: False
    ```

Answer (score 2):

using double quotes for the string to compare with worked for me:

```py
df.query('`Bob\'s Burgers` == "l"')
```